# Returning back to login page while login page automation

Tags: java, redirect, authentication, web-crawler, jsoup

I am trying to automate login to my institute website using JSoup. I tried doing with the tutorial present at https://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-login-to-website-using-post-method-example/830

But every time i do it, the elements of the same webpage(login page) is returned and not of my dashboard. seems like i am unable to login, although the login credentials are correct and working on the website.

below is my code

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
    try {

        //grab login form page first
        Response loginPageResponse = 
                Jsoup.connect("https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/checkuser1.php")
                .referrer("https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/index.php/")
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .timeout(10 * 1000)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)        
                .execute();

        System.out.println("Fetched login page");

        //get the cookies from the response, which we will post to the action URL
        Map<String, String> mapLoginPageCookies = loginPageResponse.cookies();
        String YOUR_USER_ID = "MREI2033";
        String YOUR_PASSWORD = "student1234";
        String branch_id = "9";
        //lets make data map containing all the parameters and its values found in the form
        Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapParams.put("branchid", "1");
        mapParams.put("userid", "");
        mapParams.put("pass_word", "");
        mapParams.put("branchid", "9");
        mapParams.put("sel_acad_yr", "2013-2014");
        mapParams.put("sel_sem", "Sem+1");

        System.out.println("*****************************************"+YOUR_USER_ID+YOUR_PASSWORD);
        //URL found in form's action attribute
        String strActionURL = "https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/checkuser1.php";

        Response responsePostLogin = Jsoup.connect(strActionURL) 
                //referrer will be the login page's URL
                .referrer("https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/index.php/")
                //user agent
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                //connect and read time out
                .timeout(10 * 1000)
                //post parameters
                .data(mapParams)
                //cookies received from login page
                .cookies(mapLoginPageCookies)
                //many websites redirects the user after login, so follow them
                .followRedirects(true)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + responsePostLogin.statusCode());

        //parse the document from response
        Document document = responsePostLogin.parse();
        System.out.println(document);

        //get the cookies
        Map<String, String> mapLoggedInCookies = responsePostLogin.cookies();

        /*
         * For all the subsequent requests, you need to send
         * the mapLoggedInCookies containing cookies
         */
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.icloudemserp.com/corecampus/student/student_index.php")
        .cookies(mapLoggedInCookies)
        .userAgent(userAgent)
        .get();
        System.out.println("##################################################");
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

Thanks for help:)

Comment: You have a problem with what you call subsequent requsts. It redirects to the login page. You should focus on the response you get after posting with your credentials. You're printing the response, whats the content?

Comment: Actually I am new to web-scraping so I was looking for the html contents of the webpage also it would help me know if I'm correctly logged in or not.